# when visual studio 2017 build from github source, c1083 error

Tags: c++, c, qt, build

i am new at visual studio. so i don`t know anyting.

i am :
using Visual studio 2017 
source code from https://github.com/Bionus/imgbrd-grabber

what i do :
open File-> New -> Project from existing code -> Visual c++ -> select extracted imgbrd-grabber source -> Finish

what happen :

when i build solution,
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QtTest': No such file or directory   grabber c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\tests\src\test-suite.h 4
-5.5.0\lib\src\downloader\download-query-group.h    4
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QString': No such file or directory  grabber c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\lib\src\danbooru-downloader-importer.h 4
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QNetworkAccessManager': No such file or directory    grabber c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\lib\src\custom-network-access-manager.h    4
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QtSql/QSqlDatabase': No such file or directory   grabber C:\Users\sin\Downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\lib\src\commands\sql-worker.cpp    1
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QString': No such file or directory  grabber c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\lib\src\commands\commands.h    4
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QtGui': No such file or directory    grabber c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\gui\src\viewer\zoomwindow.h    4
.

output

1>------ Build started: Project: grabber, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(387,5): warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (Debug) contains files shared from another project (ll.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(937,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of main.cpp will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are cli\src\main.cpp, crashreporter\main.cpp, gui\src\main\main.cpp, tests\src\main.cpp.
1>updater-test.cpp
1>tests\src\updater\updater-test.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtTest': No such file or directory
1>source-updater-test.cpp
1>tests\src\updater\source-updater-test.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtTest': No such file or directory
1>test-suite.cpp
1>c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\tests\src\test-suite.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtTest': No such file or directory
1>tag-test.cpp
 file: 'QSettings': No such file or directory
1>update-dialog.cpp
1>c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\gui\src\updater\update-dialog.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QDialog': No such file or directory
1>verticalscrollarea.cpp
1>c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\gui\src\ui\verticalscrollarea.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QScrollArea': No such file or directory
1>textedit.cpp
1>c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\gui\src\ui\textedit.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QTextEdit': No such file or directory
1>qclosabletabwidget.cpp
1>c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\gui\src\ui\qclosabletabwidget.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QTabWidget': No such file or directory
1>QBouton.cpp
1>c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\gui\src\ui\QBouton.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QPushButton': No such file or directory
1>QAffiche.cpp
1>c:\users\sin\downloads\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\imgbrd-grabber-5.5.0\gui\src\ui\QAffiche.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QLabel': No such file or directory
1>fixed-size-grid-layout.cpp
...
1>main.cpp
1>cli\src\main.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QCoreApplication': No such file or directory
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "grabber.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

what should i do?

Comment: Post relevant code here.

Comment: You have to install dependencies as Qt.

Comment: You should probably just download the binary release.

Comment: I Have installed QT 5.7.0.

Comment: @spectras do you mean QT binary release?

Comment: @chux red sign from almost every code

Comment: No, I mean the program you want to use offers built releases with an installer for windows. You should just use this. If you don't have solid experience in programming and the will to contribute to the project, I see no point for you to get the development version of a large scale project.

Comment: When you used `CMake` to configure and generate your Visual Studio project I would have expected it to complain about not finding `Qt`. For some reason you have a Visual Studio project with the wrong path to `Qt`.

Comment: @drescherjm do you mean i need to manually specify Qt path to Visual Studio?

Comment: @spectras do you mean i need to get built .exe files?

Comment: I mean you have obviously no knowledge of development and the tools used for this activity. So the sources of such a large project are useless for you. If you just want to use the program delete everything you downloaded and get the release instead. And if you want to learn programming, start with a simple program.

Comment: @spectras okay, i will...

Comment: ***do you mean i need to manually specify Qt path to Visual Studio?*** No. You don't do that at all with a `CMake` generated Visual Studio project. You have to make sure when you generate your Visual Studio project using `CMake` that the CMake variables for Qt point to the correct location. Although I would have expected `CMake` to fail at the generation step if it did not find Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just install Qt, you have to put it in your Include and Library dependencies under properties. Make sure your library included is the same of that which you're compiling (x86 vs x64)

[example of DXSDK in dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s12fM.png)

Comment: This is not really the best approach for a project that uses `CMake` to generate the Visual Studio project files. The reason is every time `CMake` generates your settings will be wiped out. Although if you are just trying to build one time this would work